# deploy a cloud-init server on SoftLayer through the API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-init

I'm trying to create a server on SoftLayer through the API and specify a cloud-init script to run after install. Initially I thought that would be easy, through userData (http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) but seems that's not the case as to what SoftLayer regards as userData.

I'm also having a hard time to find any examples of this working, so would highly appreciate any working example if anyone has achieved a cloud-init deployment on SoftLayer.

Thanks and regards,
Markos

Answer (score 2):

`“postInstallScriptUri”` may help you to execute an script after provisioning.
This is a REST example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject
```

Method: POST

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "hostname": "myInstanceName",
      "domain": "example.com",
      "maxMemory": 4096,
      "startCpus": 1,
      "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
      "localDiskFlag": false,
      "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "UBUNTU_LATEST",
      "datacenter": {
        "name": "dal05"
      },
      "postInstallScriptUri": "https://www.softlayer.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

References:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject section: postInstallScriptUri

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/jarteche/Getting-Started-User-Data-and-Post-Provisioning-Scripts

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation all the anwers are there https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/jarteche/Getting-Started-User-Data-and-Post-Provisioning-Scripts

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

"postInstallScriptUri

Specifies the uri location of the script to be downloaded and run after installation is complete.
Optional
Type - string"

http://bodenr.blogspot.com/2014/04/giving-your-softlayer-servers.html

Comment: This is very helpful and thanks for the links! However I want to be able to provide a cloud-init file, not bash/python etc. Seems that this is not possible.

Comment: mmm I tought that you could launch a script (using post intall script) to intall the cloud init in the machine, then run the script you want for cloud int